# Mysql select current time between two columns

Tags: mysql, sql, time, between

I have a schedule table in which I have two columns `time_from` and `time_to` with values in the 24 hour format like if the from and to are 9 Pm to 1am than the time_from and time_to would be 21 and 1 respectively.

Now I need to check if the current time falls between these two columns

If the time is 11 Pm now I should get the column whose in which column value in between 11 Pm that is 23 and 1

```
CREATE TABLE `ace_rp_inventory_locations_night` (
 `id` int(11)  NOT NULL,
 `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `time_from` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `time_to` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
 ); 
 
INSERT INTO ace_rp_inventory_locations_night (id, name, time_from, time_to)
VALUES (1, 'test', '23','1');
```

[please check sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a4c88ea/1)

this query works

```
SELECT *
FROM `ace_rp_inventory_locations_night`
WHERE time_from_1 <= '23'
AND time_to_1 >= '23'
```

if the time is in 24 Hours range that is 20 and 24 but the value for 1am is 1 and the above query does not work because 23 and 1 does not full fill the condition I am checking it with the current time so if the time is 2am I have to pass 2 in the query.

How can I use the current time and use it to query between two columns?

Comment: There's no time_from_1 or time_to_1 here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
SELECT *
FROM `ace_rp_inventory_locations_night`
WHERE (time_from_1 <= time_to_1 AND 23 between time_from_1 and time_to_1) OR
      (time_to_1 > time_to_1 AND 23 NOT BETWEEN time_from_1 and time_to_1);
```

Note:  This uses `BETWEEN` which affect how the end points of the ranges are handled.  Your question doesn't specify what to do.  You should probably be explicit about the inequalities.

Comment: this query works if the to time is up to 24 that is midnight but technically 11PM falls between 11 PM and 1AM and in this case this query returns empty but it should return that row.

Comment: @apoorvkanungo . . . As explained in the answer, there is an issue with the end points of the interval -- and your question doesn't explain how they should be handled.